# Spring AMQP project doesn't do anything

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I already struggle with this task for several days, so I decided to ask a question here.

Well, I have a remote RabbitMQ server and I only have permissions to send and receive messages. That means I can't create anything.

So, I want to receive and/or send messages. But I can't do it for some reason. The app starts, a channel creates, beans initialize etc. But a receiver and a sender simply do nothing.

I am almost sure the problem is pretty simple and I will think I'm an idiot after the answer but now I'm stuck.

The code is below. The main class is standart, without any changes.

ConfigurationClass:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class TestConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Sender sender() {
        return new Sender();
    }

    @Bean
    public Receiver receiver() {
        return new Receiver();
    }
}
```

Sender:

```
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;

public class Sender {

    @Autowired
    private RabbitTemplate template;

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000, initialDelay = 500)
    public void send() {
        String message = "Hello World!";
        this.template.convertAndSend("ExchangeName","RoutingKey", message);
        System.out.println(" [x] Sent '" + message + "'");
    }
}
```

Receiver:

```
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitHandler;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitListener;

@RabbitListener(queues = "QueueName")
public class Receiver {

    @RabbitHandler
    public void receive(String in) {
        System.out.println(" [x] Received '" + in + "'");
    }
}
```

application.properties:

```
spring.rabbitmq.host=host.com
spring.rabbitmq.port=5673
spring.rabbitmq.username=username
spring.rabbitmq.password=password
spring.rabbitmq.ssl.enabled=true
```

Logs:

```
2018-09-02 23:18:50.409  INFO 9092 --- [           main] com.application.Application    : Starting Application on WORK-PC with PID 9092 (started by Victor in ...\application)
2018-09-02 23:18:50.413  INFO 9092 --- [           main] com.application.Application    : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-09-02 23:18:50.473  INFO 9092 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@52af26ee: startup date [Sun Sep 02 23:18:50 KRAT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-09-02 23:18:51.138  INFO 9092 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitBootstrapConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitBootstrapConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6653f575] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-09-02 23:18:51.908  INFO 9092 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2018-09-02 23:18:51.916  INFO 9092 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'rabbitConnectionFactory' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2018-09-02 23:18:51.918  INFO 9092 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located managed bean 'rabbitConnectionFactory': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection:name=rabbitConnectionFactory,type=CachingConnectionFactory]
2018-09-02 23:18:51.960  INFO 9092 --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 2147483647
2018-09-02 23:18:51.970  INFO 9092 --- [cTaskExecutor-1] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: [host.com:5673]
2018-09-02 23:18:52.718  INFO 9092 --- [cTaskExecutor-1] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Created new connection: rabbitConnectionFactory#7a356a0d:0/SimpleConnection@25e05629 [delegate=amqp://username@159.69.17.11:5673/, localPort= 53053]
2018-09-02 23:18:53.158  INFO 9092 --- [           main] com.application.Application    : Started Application in 3.108 seconds (JVM running for 3.561)
```

And then nothing happens. The questions are what am I doing wrong, why does it not work how I want and how to fix it?

I understand that copypasting the whole project and asking to solve all my problems isn't a very good practice and I am sorry for this but I don't see any different way to make my code work properly at the moment. I will be glad to get any help.

Comment: Remove the  `TestConfiguration` class! You create manually Receiver and Sender, without providing anything for them to run. Just anotate Sender with `@Component`  so that Spring can pick it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to use the `@Scheduled` annotation you must first enable scheduling using `@EnableScheduling`.

Try adding it to your configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class TestConfiguration { ... }
```

Once you fix this, you'll probably need to take a look at wargre's comment as well.

Comment: You also need to add `@EnableRabbit` alongside with the `@Configuration`